# $A,B$ closed subspaces of the banach space $\ell^1$, but $A+B$ not closed

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $A = \{ (a_n)_n\in \ell^1 : (\forall n) \,a_{2n} = 0  \}$, $B = \{ (b_n)_n\in\ell^1 :(\forall n)\, b_{2n} = b_{2n-1}\frac{1}{2^n}\}$

Then according to the lecture $\operatorname{cl}(A+B)=\ell^1$.

How can I now find a sequence that is in $\ell^1$, but not in $A+B$?

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, it looks to me like actually $A+B=\ell^1$. To see that, take any $x=(a_n)_n$ in $\ell^1$.

Let $x_1$ be $x$ with even terms replaced with zeroes, $x_2$ be $x-x_1$ and $x_3$ be $x_2/2$ shifted by $1$. Then clearly $\lVert x\rVert\geq \lVert x_1\rVert,\lVert x_2\rVert,\lVert x_3\rVert$, so $x_1,x_2,x_3\in \ell^1$, and $x_1-x_3\in A$ while $x_2+x_3\in B$, and $(x_1-x_3)+(x_2+x_3)=x_1+x_2=x$.

Comment: I now found an example:
Let  $(z_n)_n\in \ell^1 : (\forall n) \,z_{2n} = \frac{1}{2^n}$ and $z_{2n-1} =0$
Then $(z_n)_n$ is not in $A+B$.

Comment: Let $x=(x_n)_n,y=(y_n)_n$ be such that $x_{2n}=0$, $x_{2n+1}=-2^{-n}$ and $y_{2n}=y_{2n+1}=2^{-n}$. Then $x\in A$, $y\in B$ and $x+y=z$.

Comment: Oh, I am really sorry. I forgot a $^n $ in my question. It should have been $B = \{ (b_n)_n\in\ell^1 :(\forall n)\, b_{2n} = b_{2n-1}/2^n\}$
Sorry for that..